# Writing part of table to an Excel file with variable sheet name

Tags: matlab, for-loop, export-to-excel

I am writing a code that I need to have output as an Excel file. Because I need to save some parts of table into different Excel files then my output is created inside a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
for j=1:5
    Table = table(ColAA(:,j),ColBB(:,j),ColCC(:,3*j-2:3*j),ColWW(:,j));
    filename_excel = [ name '_N' num2str(j) '_Seg' num2str(j) '.xlsx'];
    writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', j, 'Range','A5');
end
```

The output table is:

```
Table = 

        Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4 
        ____    ____    ____    ____

         38      71      176     124
         43      69      163     109
         38      64      131     125
         40      67      133     117
         49      64      119     122
```

where my desired table is:

```
Table = 

        ColAA   ColBB   ColCC   ColWW 
        ____    ____    ____    ____

         38      71      176     124
         43      69      163     109
         38      64      131     125
         40      67      133     117
         49      64      119     122
```

I have two questions regarding above code:

1. The name of the columns are not going to be the original name and it is just because some parts of table are needed. How could I have the original name in output,too?
2. The difficult part for me is that I need to save each sheet inside a loop with the different name and with a different indices. How could be done this inside that for loop?

Comment: I don't get any of your two questions. Your first question: is it about how to add an entry above your table where you want the matlab name of the variable to be placed? Your second question: If I am not mistaken your filename_excel is: "name_N1_Seg1.xlsx" to "name_N1_Seg5.xlsx" So I would say you have the same Name yet different indices. Is it that you also want to change the 1 behind the "N"? just change the entry inside `num2str()` then...

Comment: @TheMinion For the first question: yes I mean it. For the second question there was a typo. I edit it.

Comment: @TheMinion Not really, because I want to have different "sheet" name in each iteration.

for the first question what I expect to have is written above. By the way could you please give some explanation for your last comment?

Comment: Hey i just checked the help of table... To change the variable names just use: `Table =table(ColAA(:,k),ColBB(:,k),ColCC(:,k),ColWW(:,k),'VariableNames',{'u' 'x' 'y' 'z'});` here they would be changed to u,x,y,z so replace that with the names you want. (or save those names in a cell array just like that and use the name of the array instead)

Comment: Check out the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839669/renaming-an-excel-sheet-name-in-matlab?rq=1). It explains how to change the name of a worksheet via matlab. I am not sure what he meant with his hint though... gonna play around a bit and see if I find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit, error with changing name of sheet4 or 5 (solved)**

When changing the order of commands in the for loop as followed the code generates the right files and renames the right sheets. It was only a problem of coding order. I also realized that you do not have to preinitialize the excel files. The problem was that I first tried to change the sheet names, yet the sheets hadn't been created, so the error was "index out of dimension". By saving the table first and changing the sheet names later on, everything works.

```
for k=1:5
    Table = table(ColAA(:,k),ColBB(:,k),ColCC(:,k),ColWW(:,k),'VariableNames',Names);
    filename_excel = [ 'name_N' num2str(k) '_Seg' num2str(k) '.xls'];
    writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', k, 'Range','A5');    
    e = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % # open Activex server
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(['C:\Users\common\Documents\MATLAB\',filename_excel]); % # open file (enter full path!)
    ewb.Worksheets.Item(k).Name = Sheet_names{k}; % # rename 1st sheet
    ewb.Save % # save to the same file
    ewb.Close(false)
    e.Quit         
    result1{k}= Table;
    result2{k}=filename_excel;
end
```

**first solution below (still containing the error)**

```
ColAA= rand(100,5);
ColBB= rand(100,5)*2;
ColCC= rand(100,5)*5;
ColWW= rand(100,5)*10;
result1=cell(1,5);
result2=cell(1,5);
Names= {'ColAA', 'ColBB', 'ColCC', 'ColWW'};
Sheet_names={'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'};
for k=1:5
    Table = table(ColAA(:,k),ColBB(:,k),ColCC(:,k),ColWW(:,k),'VariableNames',Names);
    filename_excel = [ 'name_N' num2str(k) '_Seg' num2str(k) '.xls'];
    xlswrite(filename_excel,1)% # create test file
    e = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % # open Activex server
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(['C:\Users\common\Documents\MATLAB\',filename_excel]); % # open file (enter full path!)
    ewb.Worksheets.Item(k).Name = Sheet_names{k}; % # rename 1st sheet
    ewb.Save % # save to the same file
    ewb.Close(false)
    e.Quit   
    writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', k, 'Range','A5');
    result1{k}= Table;
    result2{k}=filename_excel;
end
```

First I generate my data (just random numbers).  My two result arrays are just for checking if the code works. So you can just delete those lines. Then `Names` contain my column names which you want as table names later. `Sheet_names` contain the names I want to give the sheets.

Then I added the lines from yuk's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839669/renaming-an-excel-sheet-name-in-matlab?rq=1). To change the sheet names. Therefor I had to generate those excel files first. 
Take into account that I had to change your indexing of `ColCC(:,3*j-2:3*j)` because it didn't make sense (see below) and that I changed the filename a bit, because I didn't have a `Name` variable

**Previously written in Comments (deleted for readibility)**

Also there should be a mistake in your index by ColCC. 3*j-2:3*j results in (1,0), (2,1,0), (5,4,3,2,1,0) and so on. First of all Index 0 is not allowed and secondly you have each time more entries...

And try to NOT use i,j as variable names. They are also used for complex numbers. Better use another letter or ii,jj!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Concerning `ColCC(:,3*j-2:3*j)`, it will start to choose only the colun "one to three" in first iteration and "4 to 6" in the second and so on. There is no indices with zero??!!

Comment: in matlab the indices start with one. zero is outside of matrix dimension in all cases. if you want 1-3, 4-6 and so on just use `(k*3-2):(k*3)`

Comment: Just a question about your answer. I got this error:
 `Error using interface.Microsoft_Excel_15.0_Object_Library.Sheets/Item
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: Invalid index.`

`Error in Untitled3 (line 28)
    ewb.Worksheets.Item(k).Name = Sheet_names{k}; % # rename 1st sheet`

Comment: Not sure, why you got that error. Are you using my code or yours? So did you change the indices to fit your problem? if so can you post your new code as an edit (below) your original question? SO that i can reproduce the error and check why it occurs?

Comment: @Royeh (see my last comment, forgot to address it at you). Also did you try to put the error line in comment(`% your code`) and use those cell arrays from my code? To see if the problem occurs because of excel (as it seems if you take the error code) or if its a problem of matlab or your indexing. Also did you try to display your k (`display(k)`) in your command window to check at which k the index is wrong?

Comment: I just run your code and have the mentioned error. by the way `display(k)` shows 4 and it happens for index `5`.

Comment: @Royeh the problem has been solved. The problem is that in my solution I first tried to rename the sheet and then I saved the table. Excel preinitilizes three sheets. Because of that the code tried to address sheet 4, or sheet 5 yet those sheets didn't exist yet. By saving the table first and renaming the sheet later on, this problem is solved. See the edit at the beginning of my answer for the new and hopefully working solution

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question: ***"The difficult part for me is that I need to save each sheet inside a loop with the different name and with a different indices. How could be done this inside that for loop?"*** is as follows: for example:-

1. A=rand(1,100);
2. for n=1:10
3. filename=sprintf('randomfunction_%d.xlsx',n);
4. xlswrite(filename,A,1);
5. end

Output: excel files of names: randomfunction_1, randomfunction_2,..., randomfunction_10.